# Authenticating a Chrome extension with a remote server?

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

(noob alert) Problem Statement: I have a chrome extension that takes that allows a user to bookmark a page by sending the details of bookmark to a server and storing the data under that user's profile.
This means I need to authenticate the user and then send the userID to the server every time
I send back bookmark.

Issues:

1)The bookmark is shown in the popup and then sent to the server, however if the user is not logged in(authenticated) the pop up should only show an interface that allows for user name pass not the book mark data, my issue, how would I achieve this? i know I have to use one pop file, but how would I have to separate interfaces?

2)What is the best method to authenticate the extention? and ensure that data are being sent from the extension only, i.e prevent attacks on the web service.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** You can set popup page at any time with [chrome.browserAction.setPopup](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setPopup).
So, the extension starts with the login form as the default popup under 'manifest.json'. After user login, set the browserAction popup to your main extension page.

**2)** Since the and user can edit anything on your extension code, you should prevent attacks or whatever from server-side i.e request tokens, request quota for ip and/or elapsed-time. And a simple authentication via POST under a SSL connection should be enough.

Comment: can you explain it a bit more may be with some example?